# Compare Strings with different encoding in Dart

Tags: string, dart, encoding

I need to compare 2 strings in Dart. The comparison fails because one string comes from a server and has a different encoding.

I checked and indeed : `utf8.encode(str1)` adn `utf8.encode(str2)` are different.

How can I compare those two strings?? Is there a default encoding used by Dart (that I should use as a converter for the string from the server)?

Comment: 1. Can you post specific examples/code that demonstrate your problem? 2. How did you compare `utf8.encode(str1)` and `utf8.encode(str2)`?  `utf8.encode` returns a `List<int>`, and comparing them with `==` just checks for object identity. 3. In general, the same Unicode string could be represented in different ways, even in the same encoding (e.g. precomposed vs. decomposed forms).  If you want to operate on grapheme clusters, you probably should look into using [`package:characters`](https://pub.dev/packages/characters).

Comment: The `characters` package won't help you with equality, though. If the strings genuinely contain different code points/code units, it's just different strings. Which is also why the the request to specify what you mean by "compare" is important. The strings are not equal. Do you expect them to be? Why? Do you want to compare them for something other than equality? If so, what?